# Image Slider and Stacked look of Images while page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an image slider using this link [BxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) Every thing is working fine in the slider except the stacjed loading of the slider images at the time of the page load.
While page load all the images are getting displayed one after another vertically in stacked manner which i am not able to resolve .

Here is the HTML ..

```
<div id="slider" style="padding-top:77px;">
<ul class="bxslider">
 <li>
  <img src="img/new_images/dots.jpg" />

 </li>
 <li>
  <img src="img/new_images/workforce.jpg" />

 </li>
 <li>
  <img src="img/new_images/telecom.jpg" />

 </li>
 <li>
  <img src="img/new_images/expectations.jpg" />

 </li>
 </ul>
```

And here is the jquery for it..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            adaptiveHeight: 'true',
            speed: 3000,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            pager: false
        });
        });
```

Please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

Add `preloadImages` option and set it to either `all' or`visible`.

All - will load all images and then start slider
Visible : load visible image and then start slider.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            adaptiveHeight: 'true',
            speed: 3000,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            preloadImages : 'all',
            pager: false
        });
        });
```

**Solution 2 :**

Hide parent div `<div id="slider">` and show it after slider is fully loaded..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#slider").hide();
       $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            adaptiveHeight: 'true',
            speed: 3000,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            preloadImages : 'all',
            pager: false,
            onSliderLoad : function(){
               $("#slider").fadeIn();
            }
        });
        });
```

Comment: Rahul Sir i added `preloadImages : 'all',` but result is same..What else i need to set Visible .Can you please tell me that?

Comment: No error in the console.Actually slider is coming but it is shrinked to very small images So visible also..